# What is the use of having 3 antipodal cells and 2 synergids?

Tags: botany, plant-physiology

The embryo sac which is developed from functional megaspore contains 8 nuclei.2 polar nuclei and egg fuses with sperms.3 antipodal cells and 2 synergids degenerate after fertilization.Then what is the use of having 3 antipodal cells and 2 synergids?

Answer (score 3):

This [botany textbook](https://bio.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Introductory_and_General_Biology/General_Biology_1e_(OpenStax)/6%3A_Plant_Structure_and_Function/32%3A_Plant_Reproduction/32.1%3A_Reproductive_Development_and_Structure) mentions:

> The **synergids** help guide the pollen tube for successful fertilization, after which they disintegrate.

In one of my older (1965) comprehensive books ([not in English](https://bibliotecamm.ebibliophil.ro/mon/morfologia-plantelor-qqhzcccc)) on plant morphology:

> The **synergids** usually start disintegrating before the fecundation. In special cases, they may develop into a haustorium (specialized absorbtion organ of the embryo) or even produce an additional embryo.

Later in the same book, we find that:

> apogamy (one of the three types of apomixis, alongside parthenogenesis and apospory) is the phenomenon through which the plant embryo does not develop from the egg, but the synergids or antipodes, as can be seen in *Plantago lanceolata* or *Allium odorum*.

Also, notably:

> in rare cases, the number of antipodes may vary; some plant ovules may have up to 150 antipodes, while others have two, one, on no antipodes at all.